# Web app unable to connect to server using Websocket through Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a web app which consists of client side and server side. On the client side there are only 3 files. One `index.html`, one is `app.js` which is referenced in `index.html`, the last one is an image in a sub-folder.

The server side uses express.js to build a web server but in production I decide to use Nginx to serve the static files (such as the html file, the js file and the image file).

When the user accesses the `index.html` file she can connect to the server using websocket protocol, which is coded in `app.js`. It is working fine in development mode. But after I set it up to use a Nginx I cannot connect the client to express server any more.

The express server and websocket server is listening at port 8888. But Nginx server listens at port 80. The Nginx server is still serving, but the express server always responds "Cannot Get /". My intention is to use Nginx to serve the client files and I expect users make requests using WebSocket protocol through Nginx, so I have no code for express.js routing in production ( I just create the express server and leave the routing empty), as oppose to the development mode where I use "webpack-hot-middleware" and "webpack-dev-middleware" to route the requests. But I don't know how to get rid of the "Cannot Get /" error and use my app correctly in production mode. Can anyone show me some hint?

Here is my Nginx config:

```
upstream upstream_project {
    server 127.0.0.1:8888;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/local/share/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name ws_server;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://upstream_project;
                proxy_read_timeout 240s;
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Nginx logs:

```
*1 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ::1, server: ws_server, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: Does Nginx give you any errors in the logs?

Comment: Yes I have attached the log in the update, check it out

Comment: Does port 9999 ring any bells? It seems out of place, not mentioned anywhere else but in the error.

Comment: Sorry port should be 8888 I have modified it since then.